# Virtual host Alias not routing properly

Tags: centos, virtualhost, zend-framework

I apologize if this question has been asked many times in the past.  I am not 100% sure of the exact cause of my issue and am out of google magic right now.

Basically I have a virtual host file setup with an Alias record that points to a different directory other the document root.  It basically looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName                        iBusinessCentral.com
    ServerAdmin                       sysadmin@responsivedata.com
    DocumentRoot                      /var/www/marketingsites/
    ServerAlias                       iBusinessCentral.com *.iBusinessCentral.com
    Alias                             /unsub "/var/www/unsub/site_index/"
</VirtualHost>
```

When I navigate to `ibusinesscentral.com/unsub/?randomquerystring` I am directed to the correct folder.

If I remove the query string and navigate to `ibusinesscentral.com/unsub/` I am taken to the directory in the document root.  The unsub directory is a zend application and I need to be able to navigate to different url paths like `ibusinesscentral.com/unsub/unenroll?querystring`

I have tried using `AliasMatch` instead of `Alias`.  I have also tried adding a slash after the `unsub` portion of the `Alias` record, and have not had any luck to this point.

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: When you're taken to the document root, is it just displaying the content from there or is the client browser getting a `30x` HTTP code which changes the URL being displayed (and sends a new request to the doc root)?

Comment: it actually ends up in a redirect loop and errors out.  I have a log in the document root file so I can see that it is hitting that file

Comment: What's the error, and the URL that is being redirected to?  Anything relevant in the Apache error log?

Comment: and yes the url changes.  with numerous index.php being appended

Comment: So, `/index.php/index.php`, or `/unsub/index.php/index.php`, or some other format?

Comment: `/unsub/index.php/...` I am not seeing anything relevant in the error log however I could be looking in the wrong place

Comment: Any change if you set `DirectorySlash Off` inside the virtual host?